# magento2 select data form more form

Tags: magento2.3, knockoutjs

I am doing save data to database. But i have three form in here

[image]

But when i submit. The data received only one final form

[image]

This is my code

```
 public function execute()
 {
     $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
     $courseCollecton = $this->_courseFactory->create();
     $data = (array) $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    var_dump($data);exit;
    $courseCollecton->addData($data);
    $courseCollecton->save();
    $resultRedirect->setUrl('/helloworld/index/knockout');
    return $resultRedirect;
    }
```

In my file html

```
<form action="/helloworld/index/KnockoutSave" method="POST">
<ul data-bind="foreach: courses, visible: courses().length > 0">
    <li>
        Course Name: <input data-bind="value: courseName" name="name"/>
        Number of participants: <input data-bind="value: numberOfParticipant" name="number_of_participants"/>
        Details information: <input data-bind="value: detailsInformation" name="details_information"/>
        <button data-bind="click: $parent.removeCourse.bind($parent)">Delete</button>
    </li> 
</ul>
<button type="submit">Save Course</button>
</form>
```

Please help me!

Comment: your create three tables in database

Comment: No, i have only one table

Comment: its must be create three table

Comment: Sorry. I want my form to send data via action and send data via my knockoutjs function. Do you have any way?